# Delphi - stop the application on the main form create

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe

The situation is the following one: on the application main form create event some conditions are not respected, so the application needs to close.

Yes, this is a bad design but how the application should be closed? Using the Application.MainForm.Close generates an AV. [Application.Terminate](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE2/en/Vcl.Forms.TApplication.Terminate) is not a very good choice. Other ideas?

Comment: `Application.Terminate` sure works. But it is maybe better to write your code in the .DPR file, and not in the `OnCreate` event handler of your main form...

Comment: Check the conditions before you even create the form. If you need to quite, then you can skip the .dpr code that creates forms and calls `Application.Run`. For example you can call `exit` in the body of your .dpr file.

Comment: @AndreasRejbrand - this is what I'm doing :) What I want to ask is how to terminate it inside the OnCreate event.

Comment: I'm sorry if asking here isn't proper, but why Application.Terminate isn't a good choice? I mean, the memory from the application will get freed anyway, why should you care about the order that happens?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

`Application.Terminate` works just fine.  However, keep in mind that it is a **delayed** termination, all it does is posts a `WM_QUIT` message to the calling thread's message queue, so the app will not actually terminate until `Application.Run()` is called to start processing the main thread's message queue.  Because of that, you might see the MainForm flicker onscreen momentarily before the app is actually terminated.  If you want to avoid that, you can set the `Application.ShowMainForm` property to false, eg:

```
procedure TMainForm.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
begin
  if (some condition) then
  begin
    Application.ShowMainForm := False;
    Application.Terminate;
  end;
end;
```

However, as others have stated, a better design is to do the check in the project's DPR file instead and not even create the MainForm at all if necessary, eg:

```
Application.Initialize;
if not (some condition) then
begin
  Application.CreateForm(TMainForm, MainForm);
  Application.Run;
end;
```

Answer (score 4):

Well if you want to stick to your bad design, here's a bad answer:

```
try
  Application.Terminate
except
end;
```

Answer (score 2):

```
Application.Terminate
```

is good enough unless you care to refine your design to check these conditions before the form is created (in the dpr).